How to fail a test case while Wiremock encounters Request was not matched
I am using Wiremock with version and Java 21
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

At times due to mis configuration the request doesn't match anything that is stubbed but due to resiliency built in system the error is ignored and the test case is passed. I would like to configure wiremock in such a way that the specific test case fails either by generating a RuntimeException or any other possibility in Wiremock.

WireMock 2.31.0 and above has an option in WireMockRule (the JUnit 4.x @Rule) called failOnUnmatchedRequests that should do exactly what you're describing.

Difficult to answer precisely as you haven't indicated what test language/framework you're using, but in general, Wiremock offers the ability to list unmatched requests either directly from Java or via the HTTP API.
Using that API, other languages and frameworks can get the same level of support, for example wiremock-captain for the Node.js ecosystem offers getUnmatchedRequests() for this purpose.
It's then very easy to use an afterEach() or equivalent in your testing framework to fail the test if there are unmatched requests: e.g. (in Jest/vitest for Node):
import { WireMock } from 'wiremock-captain';

const wiremock = new WireMock('http://localhost:8080');

afterEach(async () => {
  const unmatched = await wiremock.getUnmatchedRequests();
  if (unmatched.length > 0) {
    assert.fail(
      JSON.stringify(unmatched),
      '',
      `${unmatched.length} unmatched wiremock requests detected`
    );
  }
});

   


The system is not letting me accept your answer. I implemented something similar using Java, but the problem is that I need to repeat the code after every test and add it to all test classes. I was wondering if there is global option that can be customized to stop the test cases from running further and mark that specific test case as fail.
